# Handle disabling/enabling form when value changes

Tags: angular

I have a formgroup where the different formcontrols are linked to each other. Each formcontrol is enabled only if the previous one has been filled. Plus, if a formcontrol is cleared, all the next formcontrols should be cleared and disabled.

I made a litte example to explain the use case. In my example I am handling four formcontrols while in my real use case I have more formcontrols. I don't think that this implementation is elegant and it doesn't scale well. Do you have a better implementation ?

[Working example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtvwg8)

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.getMyForm();
    this.handleFormValueChanges(this.myForm);
  }

  private getMyForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      company: null,
      country: [{
        value: null,
        disabled: true
      }],
      user: [{
        value: null,
        disabled: true
      }],
      adress: [{
        value: null,
        disabled: true
      }]
    });
  }

  /**
   * Handle myForm value changes (didn't handle unsubscriptions because it is just an example)
   * TODO: Find another implementation
   */
  private handleFormValueChanges(form: FormGroup): void {
    form.get("company").valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      if (!value) {
        form.get("country").reset();
        form.get("country").disable();

        form.get("user").reset();
        form.get("user").disable();

        form.get("adress").reset();
        form.get("adress").disable();
      } else {
        form.get("country").enable();
      }
    });

    form.get("country").valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      if (!value) {
        form.get("user").reset();
        form.get("user").disable();

        form.get("adress").reset();
        form.get("adress").disable();
      } else {
        form.get("user").enable();
      }
    });

    form.get("user").valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      if (!value) {
        form.get("adress").reset();
        form.get("adress").disable();
      } else {
        form.get("adress").enable();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT: I ended up implementing a little variation of Fabio Carpinato's solution

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dzah3i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { merge } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.getMyForm();
    this.handleFormValueChanges(this.myForm);
  }

  private getMyForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      company: null,
      country: [{ value: null, disabled: true }],
      user: [{ value: null, disabled: true }],
      adress: [{ value: null, disabled: true }]
      /*
      ... other formcontrols
      */
    });
  }

  /**
   * Handle myForm value changes (didn't handle unsubscriptions nor debounceTime because it is just an example)
   */
  private handleFormValueChanges(form: FormGroup): void {
    const controlDisabledDependencies: { [controlKey: string]: string } = {
      company: null,
      country: "company",
      user: "country",
      adress: "user"
    };

    merge(
      ...Object.keys(controlDisabledDependencies).map(
        (controlKey: string) => form.get(controlKey).valueChanges
      )
    ).subscribe(() => {
      Object.keys(controlDisabledDependencies).forEach((controlKey: string) => {
        if (
          form.get(controlDisabledDependencies[controlKey]) &&
          !form.get(controlDisabledDependencies[controlKey]).value
        ) {
          form.get(controlKey).disable({ emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
          form
            .get(controlKey)
            .reset(null, { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
        } else {
          form.get(controlKey).enable({ emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe simplify this by, creating a map of dependencies.

For example, address depends on country. so you could add to your map something like:

map = ['address' => 'country']

where the keys that you use are the keys of the form controls.

then what you can do is subscribe to the form value changes and every time you enter in the subscription you will loop throught all the form control keys and start checking for the values and then decide what to disable based on the map of dependencies.

This becomes easily scalable because you can add dependencies in form controls without changing the logic, you will just need to add a record to the map.

I wrote a simple example for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qxfkdz.

Comment: The idea seems nice. But the implementation is not good as it is an infinite loop. You can try to add a console.log in the loop to see it. I'll try to implement it and I'll post it if I have something interesting.

Comment: I just solved the problem, you have to prevent the emitters when touching the form inside the value changes

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may still be the best for the scenario that you have outlined due to the sequential nature of your form.

However an alternative approach would be calling `.valueChanges()` directly on the form itself, rather than the individual form controls. This will give you a parent form object which will be emitted whenever any of the nested form controls change. You could then combine your logic into one subscribe call, e.g.

```
form.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
  if (!value.company) {
    form.get("country").reset({ emitEvent: false });
    form.get("country").disable({ emitEvent: false });
  } else {
    form.get("country").enable({ emitEvent: false });
  }

  if (!value.country) {
    form.get("user").reset({ emitEvent: false });
    form.get("user").disable({ emitEvent: false });
  } else {
    form.get("user").enable({ emitEvent: false });
  }

  ...
});
```

*Note: The { emitEvent: false } will prevent your form from triggering change detection on itself. This is important as, if not done, you will get stuck in an infinite loop of updates.*

As your design forms a kind of chain of FormControls, and each if statement would effectively be repeated on each element of the chain, I might be tempted to instead have `getMyForm()` return a `FormArray` instead of a `FormGroup`. This will allow you to iterate over your FormControls as though they were stored in an array and apply the same function to each which will scale much more effectively. This is a bit messier (but still possible) with a FormGroup.